# Initializing NSMutableDictionary to create a filter

Tags: iphone, nsmutablearray

This is a continuation question I had from a post yesterday: [Initializing NSMutableDictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6671238/initializing-nsmutabledictionary)

(It's probably a stupid question, but I don't see what I'm doing wrong.)

I liked the idea of just having "All" listed in my TableView that pops up when the filter button is pressed in order to indicate no filter applied.  I get my data from my model class sorted correctly into an NSMutableArray like so:

```
 NSArray *anArray = [dmgr.CategoryDictionary allKeys];
    self.CategoriesArray = [anArray sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
    [self.CategoriesArray insertObject:@"All" atIndex:0]; // line causes crash
```

But I want to add the "All" option to the CategoriesArray to show in the UITableView.  When I try to run it, it crashes at that line because of

```
NSArrayI insertObject:atIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x59baba0
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI insertObject:atIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x59baba0'
```

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sortedArrayUsingSelector:` returns an immutable array which is why you can't add to it. Do this to get a mutable copy.

```
self.CategoriesArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[anArray sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)]];
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems `CategoriesArray` is actually a `NSArray` instance. From [Apple's doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html) :

```
-(NSArray *)sortedArrayUsingSelector:(SEL)comparator;
```